# Why does Mysql change query execution plan based on query parameters?

Tags: mysql, sql-execution-plan, explain

I have the following query.

```
SELECT *
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN operator o ON o.id = u.id
WHERE u.user_type_id IN (2,4) AND u.is_enabled = 1 AND u.office_id = 225
```

If I run `explain` on the query above, it shows that it uses the index `IX_user_type` for the table `user`.

If I just change the `office_id` comparison value like the following, the execution plan changes.

```
SELECT *
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN operator o ON o.id = u.id
WHERE u.user_type_id IN (2,4) AND u.is_enabled = 1 AND u.office_id = 32365487
```

In this case, the `explain` shows that the indexes used for the table `user` are `fk_user_office,IX_user_is_enabled`.

I made some tests and would say, performance wise, the first execution plan is much better than the second one. Now, I know I can force Mysql to use the index I want but, I would like to understand why this happens. Why would Mysql pick an index instead of another based on a query parameter?

Comment: It checks whether that office ID is already in the index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL may decide not to use the index on `office_id` if the value you are searching for is too common.

By analogy, why doesn't a book include common words like "the" in the index at the back of the book? Because such common words occur on a majority of pages in the book. It's unnecessary to keep a list of those pages under the respective word in the index, because it's easier to tell the reader to read all the pages in the book, without the index lookup.

Similarly, if MySQL estimates that a given value you are searching for occurs on a high enough portion of the pages, it looks for another index if you have other conditions, and if none are found, then it resorts to a table-scan.

In this case, I'd ask if you can confirm that `office_id` 225 is very common in this table.

---

One more thought: The best index of all for the query you show would be a compound index on `(office_id, is_enabled, user_type)`. Then it would be able to use that index to narrow down the search by all three columns at once.

You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really) or the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU). I also have a chapter on index design in my book [SQL Antipatterns, Volume 1:
Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

Comment: Honestly, it's a very good explanation not only to this problem but the general approach to finding data. I came here by accident, I don't have much background in `SQL` yet understood this issue very quickly because of the comparison and metaphor you used. Thanks!

Comment: @SorenV.Raben You or other readers might like my book [SQL Antipatterns, Volume 1
Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/) because it has lots of similar metaphors to explain principles of SQL (which can really be applied to general programming and logic).

Comment: @BillKarwin Your explanation actually matches the data. The table user has 20 millions rows, 564k rows have office_id = 225, 84k rows have office_id = 32365487. So I guess 564k over 20 millions rows is too common, and Mysql decided to use another index. I think there is a mistake in the last line of your answer, you meant "office_id 225", right? Otherwise I'm just confused.

Comment: @scatolone, Yes, thanks, I mixed up the cases. When you specify the value that is too common, MySQL considers the index on `office_id` but says, "meh, I'll try something else." I'll edit the value in my answer above to avoid confusion.